# Rails “Getting Started” routes: can't get the "posts#index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the getting started tutorial here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

My route.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts

  root to: "welcome#index"
end
```

With the command"rake route", I get :

```
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
     root        /                         welcome#index
```

I can't find one  route `" posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index"`

My rails version is 4.0.2. Could someone give me some help please?

I added another resource as following:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
 # get "welcome/index"

  resource :posts
  resource :apples


  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

Rake routes, the output is:

```
lidong@lidong-VirtualBox:~/blog$ rake routes
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern            Controller#Action
      posts POST   /posts(.:format)       posts#create
  new_posts GET    /posts/new(.:format)   posts#new
 edit_posts GET    /posts/edit(.:format)  posts#edit
            GET    /posts(.:format)       posts#show
            PATCH  /posts(.:format)       posts#update
            PUT    /posts(.:format)       posts#update
            DELETE /posts(.:format)       posts#destroy
     apples POST   /apples(.:format)      apples#create
 new_apples GET    /apples/new(.:format)  apples#new
edit_apples GET    /apples/edit(.:format) apples#edit
            GET    /apples(.:format)      apples#show
            PATCH  /apples(.:format)      apples#update
            PUT    /apples(.:format)      apples#update
            DELETE /apples(.:format)      apples#destroy
       root GET    /                      welcome#index
```

I also can't get the 'apples#index'.

Comment: Are you sure you're pasting the full output of the command? The index action should be there.

Comment: start server and visit in browser `http://localhost:3000/posts`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I pasted all output. Pls see my further test.

Comment: @Agis, pls take a look my update. Thanks!

Comment: @itsnikolay, visit http://localhost:3000/posts, the route will go to "show", instead of "index", so i get the error: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show" and "Couldn't find Post without an ID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your routes you're declaring a singular resource:

```
resource :posts
```

You want to do istead:

```
resources :posts
```

Refer to the documentation for *[singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)* & *[plural resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)* for more info.

Comment: Hi,Agis, yes, you are right, I made a mistake. thank you very much!

Comment: @user3226757 You're welcome. Might as well *accept the answer* if it solved your problem (the "tick" icon).